# (Angular 5 + Grid List) ngx-infinite-scroll doesn't trigger

Tags: angular, angular-material2, infinite-scroll

I use Angular 5 + Material in template with a Grid List (mat-grid-list), like this:

**Template**

```
  <div class="display settings-backgroud">
    <div class="col-sm-11" style="margin-top: 40px; height:100%; overflow: scroll;"
    infiniteScroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
    (scrolled)="onScroll()"
    [scrollWindow]="false"
    >
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1.2" class="search-results">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let profile of profiles | slice:0: limit;" >
        <da-profile-card [pacient_name]="profile.name" [age]="profile.ages" [procedure]="profile.procedure" [next_procedure]="profile.next_schedule" [schedule]="profile.schedule" [type]="profile.type" [uid]="profile.uid" [attended]="profile.attended">
        </da-profile-card>
      </mat-grid-tile>

    </mat-grid-list>
  </div>
```

I use Lazy Loading Module, and my module of this component is here:

**Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AttendanceRoutingModule } from './attendance-routing.module';
import { ProfileCardComponent } from '../../da-common/components/profile-card/profile-card.component';
import { DaCommonModule } from '../../da-common/da-common.module';
import { AttendanceService } from './attendance.service'
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AttendanceRoutingModule,
    DaCommonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule
  ],
  declarations: [..],
  providers: [AttendanceService],
  entryComponents: [ProfileCardComponent]
})
export class AttendanceModule { }
```

Link for directive: https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll

I try set my height template, add overflow scroll, change position of directive but nothing work. My function callback for scroll doesn`t trigger when user scroll to bottom.

Comment: same issue here. It was working before. After including material design, it stopped working. Do u have any solutions?